# pfSense reports “The process will require x MiB more space”, still shows old version after upgrading

Tags: updates, disk-space, pfsense

Today I tried to upgrade my pfSense system. Previous version was 2.4.4 and it told me 2.4.5 was available.

I started the upgrade, it downloaded packages and somewhere reported `The process will require x MiB more space.` (the figure being somewhere in the 100–200 MB range). However, the upgrade proceeded, the system rebooted and came back up roughly an hour later (I did not monitor serial console output; reboot times on earlier updates were roughly in the same ballpark).

When the system was back up, it still reported itself as running version 2.4.4.

`df -k` revealed that the main partition, some 1.7 GB in size, was about 85% full.

**Questions:**

- Is `x MB more space is needed` just an information that the upgrade will occupy another x MB on my disk, or is that an error indicating insufficient disk space, and I need to free up an additional x MB?
- If disk space is running out, is there any way I can recover some, e.g. by emptying some caches?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, yes, the message indicates insufficient disk space.

There is a package cache, which you can empty by navigating to **Diagnostics > Command Prompt** and running:

```
echo y| pkg clean
```

This freed up another 100 MB of disk space on my system. After that I retried the update (which had been applied partially), and this time it went through.